# Looping through simplexml_load_file results

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to use simplexml_load_file to get the info in my xml file into variables.
The structure of the xml file is:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <sku></sku>
        <weight></weight>
        <Price></Price>
        <media>
            <images></images>
            <images></images>
            <images></images>
        </media>
        <short_description>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </short_description>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <sku></sku>
        <weight></weight>
        <Price></Price>
        <media>
            <images></images>
            <images></images>
            <images></images>
        </media>
        <short_description>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </short_description>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </description>
    </item>
</root>
```

Here's what I've done so far, but it's only getting the first image for each item not all the images. Apart from that it seems to be working fine.

```
$xml_url="accessories.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_url);
foreach($xml->item as $_item){
    echo $_item->sku . " - ";
    echo $_item->weight . " - ";
    echo $_item->Price . " <br/>";
    //echo $_item->short_description . " <br/><br/>";
    foreach($_item->media as $_media){
        echo $_media->images . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

My php and xml skills are pretty limited so I'd appreciate any help you can give.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use like following `foreach`

```
foreach($_item->media->images as $_media){
    echo $_media . "<br/>";
}
```

You'll see because of why with below dumped `media` data:

```
var_dump($_item->media);

object(SimpleXMLElement)[5]
  public 'images' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following loop:

```
foreach($_item->media->children() as $_img){
    echo $_img . "<br/>";
}
```

This will save you looping twice.